# extract specific word in column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Good day,

I was working for an hour for this and i want to extract specific word in specific column

here is my sql query

```
 DECLARE @string_of_text NVARCHAR(MAX)='This is sample text that will retrieve all text with CVE-2014-1775, CVE-2014-1779, CVE-2014-1799, CVE-2014-1803, and CVE-2014-2757.' 

    DECLARE @get_str NVARCHAR(MAX)=''
    DECLARE @flag INT=1
    DECLARE @move INT=1 
       WHILE  PATINDEX('%CVE-%', SUBSTRING(@string_of_text 
             ,@move,LEN(@string_of_text )))>0
 BEGIN

  SET @str=SUBSTRING(@string_of_text ,@move,LEN(@string_of_text ))
  SET @flag= PATINDEX('%CVE-%', @string_of_text )
  SET @get_str = @get_str +','+SUBSTRING(@string_of_text , @flag,13)
  SET @move=@flag+13
  END
  SELECT STUFF(@get_str ,1,1,'') 'CVE LIST'
```

Sample Result

CVE LIST
CVE-2014-1775,CVE-2014-1779,CVE-2014-1799,CVE-2014-1803,CVE-2014-2757

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Do you have a question? Some expected output based on some particular input?

Answer (score 1):

The requirement is a little ambiguous but, if you are trying to extract one or more words that exist in a string into a result set you can use [NGrams8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/). Note this example:

```
DECLARE 
  @string VARCHAR(8000) = 'This dog barked at that dog then there were two barking dogs', 
  @searchText VARCHAR(8000) = 'dog';

SELECT ng.position, ng.token
FROM dbo.ngrams8k(@string, LEN(@searchText)) ng
WHERE ng.token = @searchText;
```

**Returns:**

```
position     token
------------ --------
6            dog
25           dog
57           dog
```

To use this logic against a table you could do this:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (someId INT IDENTITY, someText VARCHAR(8000));
INSERT @table (someText)
VALUES ('this fish, that fish...'), ('more text containing the word "fish"'),('nothing');

DECLARE @searchText VARCHAR(8000) = 'Fish';

SELECT t.someId, t.someText, ng.position, ng.token
FROM @table t
CROSS APPLY dbo.ngrams8k(t.someText, LEN(@searchText)) ng
WHERE ng.token = @searchText;
```

**Returns:**

```
someId   someText                               position  token
-------- -------------------------------------- --------- ---------
1        this fish, that fish...                6         fish
1        this fish, that fish...                17        fish
2        more text containing the word "fish"   32        fish
```